# How to create a dataframe from records that has Timestamps as index?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, dictionary, datetime, python-datetime

I am trying to create a dataframe in which i have Timestamps as index but it throws error. I can use the same methodology to create a dataframe in case the index is not a Timestamp. The following codebit is a bare min example:

**Works fine**:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'1':{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},'2':{'a':1,'c':4},'3':{'b':6}})
```

output:

```
    1   2   3
a   1   1.0 NaN
b   2   NaN 6.0
c   3   4.0 NaN
```

**BREAKS**

```
o=np.arange(np.datetime64('2017-11-01 00:00:00'),np.datetime64('2017-11-01 00:00:00')+np.timedelta64(3,'D'),np.timedelta64(1,'D'))

pd.DataFrame.from_records({o[0]:{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},o[1]:{'a':1,'c':4},o[2]:{'b':6}})
```

output:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-627-f9a075f611c0> in <module>
      1 o=np.arange(np.datetime64('2017-11-01 00:00:00'),np.datetime64('2017-11-01 00:00:00')+np.timedelta64(3,'D'),np.timedelta64(1,'D'))
      2 
----> 3 pd.DataFrame.from_records({o[0]:{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},o[1]:{'a':1,'c':4},o[2]:{'b':6}})

~/anaconda3/envs/dfs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in from_records(cls, data, index, exclude, columns, coerce_float, nrows)
   1617             if columns is None:
   1618                 columns = arr_columns = ensure_index(sorted(data))
-> 1619                 arrays = [data[k] for k in columns]
   1620             else:
   1621                 arrays = []

~/anaconda3/envs/dfs/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1617             if columns is None:
   1618                 columns = arr_columns = ensure_index(sorted(data))
-> 1619                 arrays = [data[k] for k in columns]
   1620             else:
   1621                 arrays = []

KeyError: Timestamp('2017-11-01 00:00:00')
```

Please help me understand the behavior and what I am missing. Also, how do go about creating a dataframe from records that has Timestamps as indices

Comment: maybe just set the index, `pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'1':{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},'2':{'a':1,'c':4},'3':{'b':6}}).set_index(o)`?

Answer (score 0):

Change *from_records* to *from_dict* (just like in your working example)
and everything executes fine.

Another, optional hint: Since you create a **Pandas** DataFrame, use
*pandasonic* native way to create *datetime* values to use as column names:

```
o = pd.date_range(start='2017-11-01', periods=3)
```

## Edit

I noticed that if you create *o* object the way I proposed (as a
*date_range*), you can use even *from_records*.

## Edit 2

You wrote that you want *datetime* objects as the **index**, whereas
your code attempts to set them as **column names**.

If you want *datetime* objects as the **index**, run something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records({'1':{o[0]:1, o[1]:2, o[2]:3},
    '2':{o[0]:1, o[2]:4}, '3':{o[1]:6}})
```

The result is:

```
            1    2    3
2017-11-01  1  1.0  NaN
2017-11-02  2  NaN  6.0
2017-11-03  3  4.0  NaN
```

Another way to create the above result is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{'1':1, '2':1}, {'1':2, '3':6}, {'1':3, '2':4}], index=o)
```

Comment: 1. Time is of the essence for this exercise hence, I wont use pandas. I do know that I can create pandas daterange and then can use it in from_records. But again, the time constraint comes into play. I cannot modify the dictionary as you have mentioned as I am just writing a downstream software and I will be getting records in the format I have mentioned. My plan was to use a transpose